# Freeze at Startup & Shutdown

Tags: shutdown, startup, freeze, 19.04

my Ubuntu 19.04 has been acting weirdly at startup and shutdown. At startup, boot is very slow (on SSD) and sometimes freeze on desktop screen. I can't use my mouse & keyboard, with those folder and Trash shortcuts that won't appear and the drive LED indicator always active. Sometimes I can press the power button so it can bring restart/shutdown/cancel dialog and if I press 'cancel' button it solves the problem. But in other times it won't help, I have to press and hold power button to restart it.

Also, shutdown is also very buggy. It won't power off my PC and stuck in blank screen, with drive LED also always active. I have to press and hold power button again.

It's important to note that it doesn't happen on both 18.04 and 18.10. I also have changed Grub file and add `acpi=force` like I read from other site, removing `quite splash` so it probably can show log about it (but nothing works, only blank screen) and also modified some BIOS settings like fast startup and secure boot, but it seems it only worked the next time I use my PC, after that, the problems always come back.

I use 1 SSD (Ubuntu partition) with 3 WDC Blue HDD as media storage, I use this PC solely for Ubuntu (no dual boot w/ Windows or other Linux distro).

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, turns out one of the HDD has 8 bad sectors. I've swapped with new HDD and the problem is solved